# sql server unique key for each partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, primary-key, unique-key

I have a table that contain 3 columns:

ID int [primary key]

BranchRef  int [foreign key]

Code int

I need to [Code] be unique in each [BranchRef]

like:

```
ID      BranchRef      Code
1           1            1
2           1            2
3           2            1
4           2            2
5           1            3
```

I really appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a unique constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE(BranchRef, Code);
```